# What is the correct way to name an endpoint for several parameters?

Tags: java, rest, http

I have some list that comes back as a response to frontend.

For example, I have a list of customers. I have 3 variations of the answer to the frontend.
When I give the entire list of customers in its entirety.
When I need to give a specific customer.
And when I need to give customers by their status. For example status: "non-payers".

At the moment I have the following REST structure.

```
/customers

/customers/{id}

/customers?status="nonPayers"
```

I'm most interested in the last two endpoints. How right is it that I use a parameter rather than a pathVariable in a method where I get customers by their status? Is it in terms of REST?

Wouldn't it be better to do it like this:

```
/customers

/customers/byId/{id}

/customers/byStatus/{status}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct way to name an endpoint for several parameters?

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.  Any spelling that is consistent with the production rules of [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-A) is *fine*.

```
/customers/{id}
/customers?status="nonPayers"
/customers/byId/{id}
/customers/byStatus/{status}
```

These spellings are all *fine*.

---

You may find path segments more convenient when: you want to use relative references to link to nearby identifiers in the same identifier hierarchy.

You may find query parameters more convenient when: you expect to use HTML forms to capture the values that are going to be copied into the URI.

---

The correct "name" for a resource is a lot like the correct "name" for a function in your code -- any spelling that is consistent with local conventions is fine.